# Are compose.testTags modifiers compiled at buildtime for non-test builds or are they stripped?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-jetpack

I am trying to convert espresso tests to support compose.
Seems a bit awkward adding test tags in product code unless it gets removed.

e.g.

```
OutlinedTextField (
  modifier = Modifier.testTag("myField"),
```

Answer (score -1):

Having test tags in product code is something that I (and the many dev teams I have worked with) have just accepted as the price of reliable UI Automation. Test Tags are helpful for iOS/Swift, Android Compose, React Native/Appium, and Web automation. They are also the ONLY sane way to be able to re-use scenario-driven UI Automation while testing an app with different languages.

The thinking behind avoiding test tags in production code is outdated at this point, IMO.

Comment: Claiming that is outdated without actually solving the question doesn't help the community.